# passing url of images from an array to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, photo-gallery

I am using KTPhotoBrowser and i have an array that includes list of url's that's coming from a NSDictionary and i want to list those array into the array of KTPhotoBrowser which has its array as :

```
images_ = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2735/4430131154_95212b8e88_o.jpg", @"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2735/4430131154_17d8a02b8c_s.jpg", nil],
           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4001/4439826859_19ba9a6cfa_o.jpg", @"http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4001/4439826859_4215c01a16_s.jpg", nil],
           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3427/3192205971_0f494a3da2_o.jpg", @"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3427/3192205971_b7b18558db_s.jpg", nil],
           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1316/4722532733_6b73d00787_z.jpg", @"http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1316/4722532733_6b73d00787_s.jpg", nil],
           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1200/591574815_8a4a732d00_o.jpg", @"http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1200/591574815_29db79a63a_s.jpg", nil],
           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3610/3439180743_21b8799d82_o.jpg", @"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3610/3439180743_b7b07df9d4_s.jpg", nil],
           [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2721/4441122896_eec9285a67.jpg", @"http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2721/4441122896_eec9285a67_s.jpg", nil],
           nil];
```

and my array values keep on changing on every event of my app my array images are stored in an array named 'photos' and in console i get the url list as:

```
url = "http://myimage1_url.jpg",
"http://myimage2_url.jpg",
"http://myimage3_url.jpg"
```

Now how can i pass my url's to the images array of KTPhotoBrowser so that i can get the images in the 'images_' array,

Should i use for loop like

```
for(int i=0; i<photos.count ;i++)
{

get images in the 'images_' array to display the images
what code should i write here ??

}
```

or should i have to use some another technique ...

I am using this link : https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser
plaese help guys!!

Answer (score 1):

At first glance it seems that u have to implement [KTPhotoBrowserDataSource](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser/blob/master/src/KTPhotoBrowser/KTPhotoBrowserDataSource.h) protocol by creating your own data source class that will be similar to [sample data source](https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser/blob/master/src/Sample/Classes/FlickrSample/FlickrDataSource.m) and store your images in that class' instance.

**EDIT:** You can make a custom init method like this

```
- (id)initWithURLs: (NSArray*) imageURLs
{
   _images = [NSArray arrayWithArray: imageURLs];
}
```

and change data source at runtime

```
[self setDataSource: [FooDataSource initWithURLs: _imageArray1]];
```

.... after some time

```
[self setDataSource: [FooDataSource initWithURLs: _imageArray2]];
```

**EDIT 2:**

FooDataSource.h

```
@property *NSArray photos;
```

FooDataSource.m

```
@synthesize photos;
```

and all references to `photos` replace by `fooDataSource.photos`

Comment: i have only one array named photos that has url list that keeps changing on particular event in my app ...

Comment: so you could make a public property `photos` in your data source class and change it instead of your current `photos` array